# Does any Theravada Suttas / sources refer to Oozing orifices? What are the Suttas?

Tags: theravada, vipassana, pali-canon, reference-request, satipatthana

According to [Satipatthana Mula (By Sujato Bhikkhu edited by Piya Tan)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/13.4-Satipatthana-Mula-m10-sujato.pdf) Śāripūtrābhidharma Satipatthana contains a section on **oozing [orifices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_orifice)**. What exactly does Śāripūtrābhidharma sources say about **oozing [orifices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_orifice)** in English? Are there are parallels in Theravada literature especially the Tripitaka which compair with what Śāripūtrābhidharma sources say?

Comment: I think that's found in the commentaries to the Chinese Agamas.  I believe Ven. Analayo mentions it in his treatise on Satipatthana.  I have a copy at home.  I'll check when I get a moment.

Comment: Perhaps you can add an answer using this information?

Comment: Sadly I can't seem to find the source.  I know I have heard that before, however.  From what I recall, somewhere in the Chinese Agamas there is a truncated version of the 32 parts of the body contemplation.  The "oozing orifices" was one of the parts they used.  I believe Bhikkhu Bodhi also mentions this truncated contemplation in one of his Majjihima Nikaya lectures.  Again, a source eludes me right now.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena: have you emailed Mr. Piya Tan for an answer? He is most helpful (and so are you).

Comment: I think this is found in Ganda Sutta: A Boil as per answer by @santa100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AN 9.15](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an09/an09.015.than.html):

> "A boil,' monks, is another word for this body composed of the four properties, born of mother & father, fed on rice & porridge, subject to inconstancy, rubbing & massaging, breaking-up & disintegrating. It has nine openings, nine un-lanced heads. Whatever would ooze out from it would be an uncleanliness oozing out, a stench oozing out, a disgust oozing out. Whatever would be discharged from it would be an uncleanliness discharging, a stench discharging, a disgust discharging. For that reason, you should become disenchanted with this body."

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this seams a bit tangential to what I was looking for. I modified the question for more clarity.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the Sariputrabhidharma source and so won't be of much help there. Anyway, the oozing orifices description should be pretty consistent across schools. Personally, I'd go to the sutta discourses first and then use the abhidhamma if needed for any further analysis..

Comment: +1 for the answer but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I think orifice they mean [body orifices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_orifice)

Answer (score 2):

The Theravada satipatthana sutta contains the same reference:

> “Again, bhikkhus, as though he were to see a corpse thrown aside in a charnel ground, one, two, or three days dead, bloated, livid, and **oozing matter**, a bhikkhu compares this same body with it thus: ‘This body too is of the same nature, it will be like that, it is not exempt from that fate.’

(MN 10 - Bodhi, Trans)

The Visuddhimagga explains the phrase (festering = oozing):

> The festering: what is trickling with pus in broken places is festering (vipubba).
>   What is festering is the same as “the festering” (vipubbaka). Or alternatively,
>   what is festering (vipubba) is vile (kucchita) because of repulsiveness, thus it is
>   “the festering” (vipubbaka). This is a term for a corpse in that particular state.
>
> -- *Vism. VI.3 (Nyanamoli, trans)*

Comment: I think orifice they mean [body orifices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_orifice)

Comment: +1 for the answer but this is not what I was looking for.